# Show $\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Knowing $$\frac{\pi^2}{sin^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$$ how can I prove $$\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\qquad?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $z=-1/2$, and you get 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^2} = \pi^2$$
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} = \pi^2/4$$

Now, sum on +ve side and -ve side is same, and thus your answer is half of this.

Answer (score 1):

We know that,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

We also know,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$.

Now,$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4n^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{4}.\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$.

Thus,
$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

So you get, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Comment: Not really answering the question, which is about a particular way of getting the result.